# Unlock Moto E OEM Bootloader without the Passcode from Motorola

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock, motorola-moto-e

I need to unlock my Moto E phone(2nd Gen). To do this, I want to unlock the bootloader first. I got the 'get_unlock_data' and sent it to Motorola, But I did not get the passcode from them :(

Could someone tell me how to unlock the bootloader without the passcode?

Thank You

(I'm ready to take the risks - could be blown away!)

Comment: You can't unlock without Moto giving you the code. Request again using a different browser,  sometimes this happens due to the browser

Comment: I've tried chrome and firefox. You're asking me to open IE.... : ( .. aaaaaarrrrggghh.... I'll do it if I must..

Comment: For me, it was a browser problem- don't recall which but I didn't try IE :)... Who knows that may work ? It out could be a matter of their server not responding or down

Comment: No luck :( I'll wait for another day for them to respond - do you know why it cannot be unlocked - I could do such thinks on a PC - for instance F8 into the setup and do stuff. These are computer systems - why can't I just force it or something..

Comment: I can't answer with authority but that's how it is designed - remember that Moto needs to keep track of who had unlocked (warranty ) so they would make it pretty much fool proof to ensure that they are involved in it

Comment: I really don't have much to add to this, but the most common causes of being unable to obtain an unlock code are either the device is carrier branded or otherwise subsidized version (Amazon ad supported comes to mind), these devices are not eligible for unlocking... Or the token is being pasted incorrectly. I have literally unlocked dozens of Moto devices, all using Chrome.

Comment: I finally received the code yesterday from Motorola . 10 emails with the same code :). Well- the answer to my question must be Patience!!  Now going to root my Moto E